# NoMethodError in PostsController#create

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror

Forgive my ignorance but I am brand new not only to Ruby but programming in general.  I am working through the example on edge guides at rubyonrails.org. and am receiving the following error and despite reviewing every piece of code I've typed since the app last worked I am unable to fix it.

> NoMethodError in PostsController#create
>
> undefined method `permit' for {"title"=>"",
>   "text"=>""}:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess

And this is what my posts_controller.rb looks like:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))

    if @post.save
      redirect_to action: :show, id: @post.id
    else
      render 'new'
    end    
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find{params[:id]}
  end  

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end        
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: The `params` you get in a controller action is an instance of the `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` class, and `permit` is not an instance method for that class, so this definitely won't work.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Have any of the answers solved your problem? If so, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of this line:

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
```

Try this

```
 @post = Post.new(params[:post])
```

It looks like you ran across [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) and had a few tutorial mixups.

If you do want to use `strong_parameters`, add the gem to your Gemfile and create an initializer with the following:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection)
```

Then your controller can be:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to action: :show, id: @post.id
    else
      render 'new'
    end    
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find_by_id(params[:id].to_i)
  end  

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end    

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Which version of Rails are you using? `#permit` is a new feature to be added in Rails 4.0 to prevent mass assignment. So if you're on 3.2, you will need to add the `strong_parameters` gem to support this functionality. Alternatively, you can drop the `.permit(:title, :text)` in the `PostsController#create` and add the following to your `Post` model:

```
attr_accessible :title, :text
```

This is done in order to prevent a attacker from tampering with the submitted form data and updating some unauthorized field (e.g. 'is_admin', or something of the sort.

More details [here](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/).

Comment: I'm on 3.2.13.  I'll give these a shot and let you all know how it goes.  Thank you for the quick responses!!!

Comment: This is the answer. The OP is trying to implement a Rails 4 feature in Rails 3.2. 

attr_accessible is the right answer and the pre-4.0 way to handle mass assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The guide you are following is for rails4 and you must have another version of rails installed.

Follow this for rails 3.2

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/

Answer (score 1):

In file  `posts_controller.rb` , you need to add those two methods :

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  end
end
```

then you add to the file  `app/models/post.rb` this line :

> attr_accessible :title, :text

I hope this helps you to solve the problem :), for me it works  ;)